# mootools.svn.js shows error in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, mootools

Script for a slider header that uses mootools works just fine in IE7 and 9, but pops an error in 8.  Works fine in all other browsers too.

```
Line: 2148
Char: 3
Error: Invalid procedure call or argument
Code: 0
URL: (Path to mootools.svn.js)
```

The code is:

```
setStyle: function(property, value) {
    switch (property) {
        case 'opacity': 
            return this.setOpacity(parseFloat(value));
        case 'float': 
            property = (window.ie) ? 'styleFloat' : 'cssFloat';
    }
    property = property.camelCase();
    switch ($type(value)) {
        case 'number': 
            if (!['zIndex', 'zoom'].contains(property)) 
                value += 'px'; 
            break;
        case 'array': 
            value = 'rgb(' + value.join(',') + ')';
    }
    this.style[property] = value;
    return this;
},
```

Line 2148 is this:

```
this.style[property] = value;
```

I've been searching for an answer for days and I'm not very good with JavaScript, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you create an example on http://jsfiddle.net for testing? Or is this page already online?

Comment: where does that `window.ie` come from?

Answer (score 2):

are you using http://code.google.com/p/cnetjavascript/downloads/detail?name=mootools.svn.js&can=2&q= ?

it is **deprecated** and if you check the source for references to `window.ie` it looks like the following snippet. if you are using this you should really consider upgrading to a more recent and supported javascript framework.

```js
/*
Class: window
    Some properties are attached to the window object by the browser detection.

Properties:
    window.ie - will be set to true if the current browser is internet explorer (any).
    window.ie6 - will be set to true if the current browser is internet explorer 6.
    window.ie7 - will be set to true if the current browser is internet explorer 7.
    window.khtml - will be set to true if the current browser is Safari/Konqueror.
    window.gecko - will be set to true if the current browser is Mozilla/Gecko.
*/

if (window.ActiveXObject) window.ie = window[window.XMLHttpRequest ? 'ie7' : 'ie6'] = true;
else if (document.childNodes && !document.all && !navigator.taintEnabled) window.khtml = true;
else if (document.getBoxObjectFor != null) window.gecko = true;
```

Comment: that won't be it, though he's using a VERY old version of mootools - one that should be banned.

Answer (score 1):

when you have an exception after a `this.style[property] = value` call, it may be an actual issue with an invalid value - such as `width: -5` or 'scroll: "none"' or similar.

just debug this and see what property and value it is and catch it upstream - often due to easing / elasticity (eg. Fx.morph on height with a custom transition to 0).

if you cannot prevent the value from being invalid, stick a try/catch around the call for the animation or whatever triggers it.